# Add support to the API to do all non-moderator actions that a user can do

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, api, deleted-posts

It does not appear that the API supports viewing of deleted posts, which is what a 10k user or moderator can do on a site. Although I don't expect diamond moderator actions to be exposed, I would expect that the API could be used to retrieve deleted posts, identify posts that are not only deleted but hidden due to spam or offensive content, and even information about the deletion (deleted by author, deleted by votes, etc).

For example, when querying `/questions/{ids}`, I would expect that passing in the ID of a deleted question would return the selected data about the question, even if it were deleted. I would also expect `/search/` to only return non-deleted posts, but `/search/advanced` to have the capability to flag if deleted posts should be returned or not.

In short, if I can do something in the web UI as a user, I should be able to do it through the API if I'm using a token associated with that user.

Comment: Per [this prior staff comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352919/make-whether-a-deleted-question-was-deleted-voluntarily-or-for-moderation-reason#comment1179736_352919), the API works off of a model that completely ignores deleted content.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That explains why I couldn't find anything about it. I didn't look at the comments to see an answer. It does seem like a valuable change to consider, but it isn't clear what the effort is.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That comment isn't entirely accurate. The SE API can be used to raise flags on deleted posts, so it's not *entirely* divorced from deleted content.