# Post notice should indicate a self-deletion even if the author's account has been deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-accounts, deleted-posts, post-notices, self-delete

When a user deletes their own post, the banner at the top of the post will clearly tell it was done by the post author:

[image: This post is hidden. It was deleted 20 hours ago by the post author.]

However, when the account has been deleted, it will revert back to showing the username. This may be a bit confusing, especially on longer posts where you have to scroll down several pages to check the author's name. It would show the same way if this was a post deleted by a user who is no longer a moderator.

[image: This post is hidden. It was deleted 2 years ago by userxxxxxx.]

Comment: Possibly related: [Questions voluntarily deleted by their authors, who later delete their accounts show to <10k users as "removed for reasons for moderation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313055/questions-voluntarily-deleted-by-their-authors-who-later-delete-their-accounts)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I think so, yes. The system might be comparing the same values (owner ID of the post and user ID) and after deleting the account they are both NULL and hence [not equal to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1833949/4751173).

Comment: Fix should be easy, adding another field somewhere "DeletedByAuthor" with 0/1 values.

Answer (score 4):

The text...

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

...is a conditional based on the fact that we can positively identify that the user who wrote the post is in fact the same user who "voted" to delete it. This is because we can compare `Posts.OwnerId` and `Votes.UserId` and, if they are equal (and > 0, and not null), then we know the author deleted their own post.

When a user is *removed*, all associations with their content are also removed, so we can no longer be certain that the users are the same. For example, the `OwnerId` is set to `NULL` or `Votes.UserId` is set to `NULL` or both. Or, in some cases, one or the other is set the community user (-1), or the row is deleted altogether.

The fallback text when this determination can no longer be made shows that the code assumes moderation was at play - it can no longer be certain that the author is the one who deleted the post because the data simply isn't there or, if it was set to the community user, that moderation of some kind was involved. It's a reasonable assumption when we no longer know anything at all about the original user involved.

We currently don't have a way *other than this UserId association* to denote that a post was deleted by its author. So perhaps this could be converted into a feature request - for example, [a `DeletedByAuthor` column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371681/post-notice-should-indicate-a-self-deletion-even-if-the-authors-account-has-bee#comment1289925_371681) that could maintain state even after all the specific `UserId` values were removed from the various tables.

Simpler, though, would be to have the fallback text be less assertive about why the post was removed, in lieu of being able to know for sure. It could simply say:

> This question was removed from [site name] by the author or by a moderator. Please refer to...

Or even simpler:

> This question was removed from [site name]. Please refer to...

If the question was deleted and the user who wrote the post was also deleted, I'm not sure how important it is to be sure whether the author deleted their own post first or if the question was deleted by a moderator (or a pile-on by peers?) before or after the user was removed. Is it to identify the (probably non-existent) case where a moderator deleted a post, the user was removed from the site, and then the moderator resigned and also asked their content to be removed? Because if the post was deleted through moderation (e.g. for spam) before or after the user was removed, it should say this:

> [image: This post is hidden. It was flagged as spam or offensive content...]

Which brings me back to thinking this is a bug and there probably isn't a case where the current fallback is correct. So my suggestion to just make the fallback text simpler seems like the best and most direct solution (since actual known moderation reasons will be kept intact whether the user is removed or not, and the only case we'd need a fallback is when the user self-deleted and no longer exists - but, due to ever-increasing privacy regulations, we probably don't even want to *imply* that we ever even knew that the author and the deleter were the same person or that they existed at all).

If the post is gone, and the user is gone, how much detail do we really still need about *exactly* what happened to the post? Isn't "this post was deleted" sufficient?

Comment: "If the post is gone, and the user is gone, how much detail do we really still need about exactly what happened to the post? Isn't "this post was deleted" sufficient?" Knowing this crowd, *All* the detail >_>

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Of course. But _need_ is different from _want_ and even... well, _think_ they need. :-) Having been involved in a lot of work this year to shore up privacy profiles, it is unlikely anyone will go out of their way to provide _more_ info about people - especially people who have requested to be removed.

Comment: You might consider posting a similar response to my [related issue report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313055/questions-voluntarily-deleted-by-their-authors-who-later-delete-their-accounts) about the 404 page of deleted questions for <10k users, which changes from saying "voluntarily removed by its author" to "removed for reasons of moderation" once the author deletes their profile.