# Find posts deleted by authors, that deleted their own account later

Tags: support, data-explorer, deleted-accounts, deleted-posts

How can we find posts deleted by their author that deleted their own account later?

Comment: If you're talking about finding all such posts (posted by any deleted user), I'm not sure whether that is possible. If you're talking about finding all of a *specific* deleted user's posts (and you know the user's ID), that feature does exist for mods and staff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.

SEDE only keeps [very limited fields for deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431). When you query [PostsWithDeleted where the deletiondate is not null](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1710448) you will find that OwnerUserId and OwnerDisplayname are always null. So there is no convenient way to obtain that data from the public sources.

You'll need SE staff to run such query, assuming its results serve a legit goal.

Comment: A "legit goal" would be to find instances of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313055/questions-voluntarily-deleted-by-their-authors-who-later-delete-their-accounts).

Comment: @Sonic I don't see *just* looking for instances of that issue to be an inherently legit goal for looking for such content. The desire to find some additional questions fitting that criteria *could be* legit, but it would, IMO, depend on *why* the person wanted to go looking for more examples. The bug report question you linked already links to an example question. *Why* is there a need/desire to look for more? What benefit might be gained? I'm *not* actually asking you those questions. I'm saying that those are some of the considerations as to a request *now* for that data being legitimate.